# Azure Data Factory dynamic Copy Activity with multiple tables in source and destination using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-factory

I have written this `copy activity` in `C#` `.NET` that moves data from `Sql Server` to `Azure`. It uses one table at present for both source and destination and here is my code

```
       private DatasetResource CreateDataSetResourceSqlServer(string tableName)
        {
            DatasetResource sqlDatasetResource = new DatasetResource(
                new SqlServerTableDataset
                {
                    LinkedServiceName = new LinkedServiceReference(LinkedServiceReferenceNameSqlServer),
                    TableName = tableName
                }
             );
            return sqlDatasetResource;
        }
        private CopyActivity CreateCopyActivity()
        {
            return new CopyActivity
            {
                Name = CopyActivityNameSqlServerToAzure,
                Inputs = new List<DatasetReference>() { new DatasetReference() { ReferenceName = DataSetNameSqlServer } },
                Outputs = new List<DatasetReference>() { new DatasetReference() { ReferenceName = DataSetNameAzureSql } },
                Source = new SqlSource { SqlReaderQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table1" },
                Sink = new SqlSink { }
            };
        }
```

this works but is not a `scalable` solution though `DataSet` creation is dynamic but `CopyActivity` isn't. I have 50 tables in source and destination and I have an idea that if I list all my table names in file and iterate through them but then how do i make `CopyActivity` with dynamic `Source` that can copy data for multiple tables. Also If new tables are added in future in file I don't have to write `CopyActivity` per table.
could any one help

Comment: Please don't include images with your code in. Copy/paste is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

you could use for each activity and the expression language. Please reference the example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#iteration-expression-language

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the C# you may or may not use foreach activity as you will be reading the tablename into a variable and loop it through . I could suggest you to create a parameter in ADF for the tablename and use that in Source and the Sink.